# How to get all decendant li of ul even under another ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, attr

how can i get "all" attr("class") of li under ul#div and return it as array with out repeating same value of class?

```
<ul id="div">
  <li class="a"></li>
  <li class="aa">
    <ul id="set">
      <li class="aa1"></li>
      <li class="aa2"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="aaa"></li>
  <li class="aaa"></li>
  <li class="aaa"></li>
  <li class="a"></li>  
</ul>
```

im looking for return like this:

return class in array(a,aa,aa1,aa2,aaa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all `<li>` descendants of `<ul>` that have a `class` attribute, make it into a standard array, then get classes of each one.

```js
var classes = $('ul li[class]').toArray().map(function(el) { return el.className });
console.log(classes);
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="div">
  <li class="a"></li>
  <li class="aa">
    <ul id="set">
      <li class="aa1"></li>
      <li class="aa2"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="aaa"></li>
  <li class="aaa"></li>
  <li class="aaa"></li>
  <li class="a"></li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: I'd say `$('#div li[class]')`

Comment: Ah, right. I could have sworn the question was "including ul's"; but seems not.

Comment: the script is work but what i need is the class="value", because the return was the content of the li not the class="value"

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand your comment. None of the elements in the example have any content to return, and even if there was, my script is not touching the content at all, only class names.

Comment: thanks, i made same adjustment to my selector and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

With pure JavaScript, you could do something like this

```
var node = document.getElementById("div");
var children = node.childNodes;
var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
{
    if (typeof children[i].className !== "undefined")
        output.push(children[i].className);
}
```